# Building dojo leaves layer file with "//>>built"

Tags: build, dojo

I was building dojo from util/buildscripts/build.sh and including my custom modules resulted in a layer file(example dojo.js) to be just containing text "//>>built".

Answer (score 1):

The issue is discussed here and solves the problem

http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/Building-of-1-7-2-custom-module-leaves-some-js-files-empty-td3781592.html

Comment: Also using closure under layerOptimize will remove some dead code and after removing the dead code there may be some trailling commas which cannot be removed .So change layerOptimize:"closure" to layerOptimize:"shrinksafe"